# The class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked

Tags: ios, swift, realm, imessage

I have set **MLSData** on `AppDelegate` as Below

```
func getMLSBoards() {
    Service.shared.getMlsBoards(completion: { (mlsResponse) in

        if mlsResponse?.respCode == Code.success.rawValue {
            Defaults.shared.setMLSBoards((mlsResponse?.data?.mlsBoard)!, forKey: Default.mlsBoards)

            for mlsBoard in (mlsResponse?.data?.mlsBoard)! {
                if mlsBoard.id == 1 {
                    Defaults.shared.setInt(mlsBoard.id!, forKey: Constants.kProviderID)
                    Defaults.shared.setString(mlsBoard.title!, forKey: Constants.kProviderValue)
                    Defaults.shared.setMLSBoard(mlsBoard, forKey: Default.mlsBoard)
                }
            }

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init(Notifications.nReceivedMetadata), object: nil)
        }
    })
}
```

and I want to get that **MLSData** on my **iMessage** APP

```
let mlsBoard = Defaults.shared.getMLSBoards(forKey: Default.mlsBoards)
```

but my app is crash with this message

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '***
>   -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (Sarnail.MlsBoard) for key (NS.objects); the class may be
>   defined in source code or a library that is not linked'

I had tried this also

```
NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("Employee", forClass: Employee.self)
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Employee.self, for: "Employee")
```

but it not works for me
Some one please help me!

Comment: let mlsBoard = Defaults.shared.getMLSBoards(forKey: Default.mlsBoards)
Before this line check by the help of breakpoint what do you have in "Default.mlsBoards"